# Programmatically launch IE Mobile favorites screen

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-mobile, pocketpc

Is there any way to launch IE Mobile's "Favorites" screen directly by
specifying any command line parameter?

Answer (score 5):

How about running IE with the HTML favorites file as a parameter?

> IExplore file://\windows\fav.htm

Answer (score 3):

I think this is going to be quite difficult without code.

Two options come to mind:

- Find out what Windows messages IE sends to open the favorites screen and replay these in your application. You would first need to see if IE is running and if it is bring it to the foreground. If not then start the process. Maybe you can use Windows CE Remote Spy to find the right Window and information about the Favorites button?
- Other option is to work against the place where IE stores it's favorites information. You would have to write your own UI to parse the favorites etc.

Answer (score 3):

Create a link file with this line: `26#"\Windows\iexplore.exe" -f`